# How to subscribe to changes Knockout Observable in TypeScript?

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, observable

How to subscribe to changes Knockout Observable in TypeScript?

```
Data :Knockoutobservable<string> = ko.Observable<string>();
```

I need something like:

```
Data.subscribe(function(e){})??
```

Answer (score 4):

Type script is just way to write your JavaScript. It does not make any difference to knockout.

So, you can write your subscribe in following manner (same like in javascript)

```
Data.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert(newValue);
});
```

Comment: I did but typeScript is not gnerating javascript errorr ' duplicate identifier'  public SelectedItem = ko.observable<string>();     
        SelectedItem.subscribe(function(newValue)
        {
            alert(newValue);
        });

Comment: You will get ' duplicate identifier' when you are trying to declare same identifier in same scope.Write this line SelectedItem.subscribe(function(newValue) { alert(newValue); });  in to constructor. So that it will get registerd with 'SelectedItem'

Answer (score 2):

this Typescript...

```
class Car {
    data:KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor(data: string) {
        this.data = ko.observable(data);
        this.data.subscribe((newData) => {
            alert("My data changed to: " + newData);
        });
    }
}
```

will compile to the following JavaScript...

```
var Car = (function () {
    function Car(data) {
        this.data = ko.observable(data);
        this.data.subscribe(function (newData) {
            alert("My data changed to: " + newData);
        });
    }
    return Car;
})();
```